# MSM - Only super admin can switch sites

Tags: multi-site-manager

I'm running MSM on MAMP PRO and I though everything was setup correctly.

I have configured 3 sites, and when logged into the CP using the super admin account, I can switch between them without a problem.

However when logged in with a member assigned to another member group (which as far as I can see has pretty much all the same privileges as the SA), switching between sites no longer works.

Instead I just get "An Error Was Encountered - You are not authorized to access this page"

Any idea as to where I can start looking to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies. I think the issue has been solved. I set all 3 sites to cookies only, cleared the browser and now it appears to be working.